# Emit NestJS event locally (in-process EventPattern trigger)

Tags: events, microservices, nestjs

I am using `@nest/microservices` with the latest version of `nextjs 6.x`. I have inter-process communication working correctly using `@EventPattern` and `ClientProxy.emit.`

This works fine locally but when I deploy I use `AWS Eventbridge` for communication directly to a `lambda`.  This could of course be any transport mechanism so my question is not related to `Eventbridge` per se.

What I need to do is receive a payload into my `lambda` and then I need to push this into the `nestjs microservices` lifecycle so that my event can be processed using the `@EventHandler(...)`. So I am looking for something like a `publishLocal` or `emitLocal` so that the communication stays `in-process`.

I would be bootstrapping the `nestjs` application context with `NestFactory.createApplicationContext(...)`, I am just not sure how I can process the subscription payload in-process in a decoupled fashion.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Mark